# Refactoring POST Request to Use Callback in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

I have a function using Angular's http to handle a REST POST request for the creation of a new customer record in my Angular 2 app. That was working as expected and looks like this:

```
createCustomer() {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    const body = {
        isEnrolling: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        name: {
            first: '',
            last: ''
        }
    };

    return this._http.post
    (`https://api.somesite.com/${this.ver}/customers?apikey=${this.key}`,
    body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

I'm calling this service method in my component and then immediately navigating to the newly created doc, like this:

```
private createCustomer()
{
    this.customerService.createCustomer().subscribe(
    data => {
        this.router.navigate(['/customer', data._id]);
        return true;
    },
    error => {
        return Observable.throw(error);
    });
}
```

As mentioned, all of the above is working.

Now I'm trying to refactor this API call so as to use a universal POST request method that a co-worker set up. He's set it up to use callbacks instead of the mapping I'm doing now. This is what his POST method looks like:

```
public post(params: {
    req: string,
    reqArgs?: any,
    reqBody?: any,
    callback?: IRequestCallback
}): Observable<Response>
{
    params['reqType'] = 'post';

    return this.runHttpRequest(params);
}
```

The `IRequestCallback` interface used here looks like this:

```
export interface IRequestCallback
{
    (response: IResponse);
}
```

And the `IResponse` interface looks like this:

```
export interface IResponse
{
    ok?: boolean;

    data?: any;

    status?: number;

    statusText?: string;
}
```

So that part of my function that I'm homing in on changing to work with this new POST method is this part:

```
return this._http.post
(`https://api.somesite.com/${this.ver}/customers?apikey=${this.key}`,
body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

This is how I tried refactoring the createCustomer() function to work with the apiService POST method:

```
createCustomer(callback?: Function) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    const body = {
        isEnrolling: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
        name: {
            first: '',
            last: ''
        }
    };

    return this.apiService.post({
        req: `/customers`, reqBody: body, callback: function (response)
        {
            const res = response;

            if (res && res.status === 200)
            {
                console.log(res.json());
                return res.json();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Not able to complete createCustomer() function...');
            }

            callback(response);

        }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

But in doing this I get this error:

> Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Response'.
>
> And is in reference to this (part of the component code I listed above):

```
this.router.navigate(['/customer', data._id]);
```

My question is two-fold:

1.) Why is this error being thrown? That's not clear to me.

2.) How can I refactor my re-factored "createCustomer()" function to work with the POST request format expected by the apiService?

Comment: Did you try to console.log res object inside service and then in service call? See what does it show?

Comment: Because of the compilation error I mentioned, I'm not able to run as is. So I can't print anything to the console.